# Interpolating missing values useing np.interp

Tags: python, numpy, interpolation

Im stuck with a the following problem:

Using a different code i generate files that produce x and y values, frequencies and intensities. I use 2 different methods and consequently get 2 different sets of x,y's. The idea is to norm the one with the other to get a normalized flux. The auxillary code however uses different sampling rates as it auto adjusts its rate. Normalizing will thus be not possible as the arries have different lengths!

Solution interpolate the missing values. THe most suited way I found is by using np.interp. Well:

Heres my code:

```
 #Freq2_f1 is the frequency of File 1 - high sampling rate
 #Freq2_f2 is frequency of File2 - low sampling rate
 #Inten2_f1 is intensity of File1 -  high sampling rate
 #Inten2_f2 is intensity of File 2 - low sampling rate

Freq_f2=filearray2[0:num2-3]
Freq1_f2 = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(Freq_f2))
Freq2_f2=np.array(map(float,Freq1_f2))
Inten_f2=filearray2[num2+1:len(filearray2)]
Inten1_f2 = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(Inten_f2))
Inten2_f2=np.array(map(float,Inten1_f2))


Inten_int=np.interp(Freq2_f1,Freq2_f2,Inten2_f2)
#Inten_int=griddata(Freq2_f2,Inten2_f2,Freq2_f1,method='linear')
print
print 'Input frequency=highly sampled frequency'
print(Freq2_f1)
print 'Length of input frequency',len(Freq2_f1)
print 'Frequency of less sampled data'
print(Freq2_f2)
print 'Length of less sampled intensity', len(Freq2_f1)
print 'Intensity of less sampled data'
print(Inten2_f2)
print 'Length of less sampled frequency', len(Freq2_f2)
print 'Output array of np.interp '
print(Inten_int)
print 'Length of interpolated intensity', len(Inten_int)
```

This is what it yields: 
As you can see The output array Inten_int is just a **constant** of 1.051e-02!

```
Input frequency=highly sampled frequency
[  6.87718000e+01   6.86571000e+01   6.85425900e+01 ...,   3.92414600e-03
3.91760100e-03   3.56145800e-03]
Length of input frequency 9576
Frequency of less sampled data
[  6.87718000e+01   6.86571000e+01   6.85425900e+01 ...,   3.92347200e-03
3.91692900e-03   3.56145800e-03]
Length of less sampled frequency 5857
Intensity of less sampled data
[  1.02640000e-36   1.20500000e-36   1.42720000e-36 ...,   1.19530000e-02
1.19260000e-02   1.05100000e-02]
Length of less sampled intensity 5857
Output array of np.interp 
[  1.05100000e-02   1.05100000e-02   1.05100000e-02 ...,   1.05100000e-02
1.05100000e-02   1.02640000e-36]
Length of interpolated intensity 9576
```

I have no idea why!
The values of the frequencies are (monotonously) increasing as demanded by np.interp

I apologize for naming the variables this crappy :(

Answer (score 2):

From [docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.interp.html), the signature is:

```
np.interp(x, xp, fp, left=None, right=None, period=None)
```

and:

> ...
>
> **xp**: 1-D sequence of floats -- The x-coordinates of the data points, **must be increasing if argument period is not specified.** ...

(emphasis is mine.)

Your `xp` (`Freq2_f2`) looks like it is *decreasing* -- not increasing.

```
Frequency of less sampled data
[  6.87718000e+01   6.86571000e+01   6.85425900e+01 ...,   3.92347200e-03 3.91692900e-03   3.56145800e-03]
```

you could probably try:

```
Inten_int = np.interp(Freq2_f1, Freq2_f2[::-1], Inten2_f2[::-1])
```

Comment: Thank you! That was the issue .. sometimes you just dont see the obvious :(